# Install pgRouting on Postgres 9.1 and Win 32

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, 32bit

I referred some documents on GIS-stackexchange and over internet regarding installation of pgRouting on Postgres v9.1 and windows 32. 
I am not getting the correct version of pgRouting to install.
Can anyone guide me to get the right pgRouting version for Postgres 9.1 and windows 32.

I tried winnie builds and sanak builds but I am getting errors after running SQL query CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;. The error are:

1. Using winnie build for Postgres 9.1 and win 64
   ERROR: incompatible library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/librouting.dll": version mismatch
2. Using pgRouting for Postgres 9.2 and win 32
   ERROR: incompatible library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/librouting.dll": version mismatch
3. Using Sanak build:
   ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/librouting_bd.dll": The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

Your version of PostgreSQL must match with the version of the DLL it was compiled for. Also 32bit or 64bit architecture matters, I think.

There should be various versions available on the Winnie build server: http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/

Comment: I have checked on Winnie build server, I did not found the build for Postgres 9.1 and Win 32. I tried Win 64 build, its not working. So Yes, 32bit or 64bit architecture matters.                                                     Is there any alternate site to find this build or do I have to change the Postgres version.

Comment: I'm not a Windows users, so other people might no better. But as far as I know, the Winnie build server is currently the best choice for Windows binaries.

Comment: I'm exactly the same problem with my version is 9.1 with 32-bit windows and I can not install pgrouting, how you solved it?